# Golang - Python interoperability

Tags: python, go, language-interoperability

Is there any way to use python libraries like `pandas`, `numpy`, `scipy`, `pytorch`, ... from Go programming language?

I know that these libraries are not programmed in python but in c, so maybe it is easy to call funcions from golang.

Comment: Be aware these libraries are *not* programmed in C. They use extensions that are programmed in C, via wrappers programmed for the Python C-API, often via more wrappers programmed in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how practical it would be but if it's a little piece of code you can run it using go's "os/exec" package like so:

```
exec.Command("python",  "-c", "import pythonfile; print pythonfile.cat_strings('foo', 'bar')")
```